# powershell will not keep commands in function call

Tags: powershell

I am trying to call a new powershell environment from powershell that sets a path location and imports a module...

at first glance it appears to do this, however... when trying to run any of the functions in the module (psm1 and ps1 files) it cannot find the module.

it appears to be dropping everything apart form the set location

heres my code

```
function NewEnv($path)
{   
$new = powershell -NoExit -command "&{cpath $path}" 
}

function cpath($path)
{
cd $path;  
PGCheck $path
Import-Module ".\myModule"
get-Module

}
```

Comment: I'm surprised `$new` even changes your directory. You're starting a brand new powershell process and asking it to execute a command you've not defined. You'd need to redefine `cpath` and re-import your modules as part of the `-command` argument

Comment: @arco444: well, it has the `-NoExit`, so it wouldn't even return to the parent process. But `cpath` wouldn't be defined anyway, then.

Comment: i was surprised too when it worked, i was originally intending just calling $new from powershell when i was workign directly in there..  

so.... are you saying i need to do it something like 

`powershell -NoExit -command "&{cd $path; PGCheck $pathm Import-Module .\mymodule}" `

Comment: @SimonPrice Yes, something along those lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

```
Powershell -NoExit -command "&{cd $path; PGCheck $path; Import-Module .\mymodule}"
```